# Linear Algebra Eigenval and Eigenvec related question.

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Show that A = $\left[\begin{array}{ccc}
0 &0 &0\cr
-4 &2 &2\cr
6 &-3 &-3
\end{array}\right]$ and $B=\left[\begin{array}{ccc}
-9 &-3 &-9\cr
15 &5 &15\cr
3 &1 &3
\end{array}\right]$ are similar matrices by finding an invertible matrix  satisfying $A=P^{-1} B P$ (Hint: the matrices  and  are diagonalizable with the same eigenvalues.)

$P^{-1}=\left[\begin{array}{ccc}
 &  & \cr
  &  & \cr
  &  & 
\end{array}\right]$ and $P=\left[\begin{array}{ccc}
 &  & \cr
  &  & \cr
  &  & 
\end{array}\right]$

I started to find the eigenvalue and eigenvector of B, but I cannot get it right. What should I do next?

Comment: This has been asked many times on MSE, for example: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/601836/given-two-similar-matrices-a-b-is-there-a-way-to-find-an-invertible-matrix, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/773781/show-a-and-b-are-similar-to-same-diagonal-matrix-then-find-inv-matrix-p, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1690602/showing-that-two-matrices-are-similar-by-showing-they-are-similar-to-the-same-di

Comment: Thanks you! @Moo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily see that the null space for the matrices has dimension $2$ therefore $\lambda=0$ are $2$ eigenvalues and by the trace we can see that also $\lambda=-1$ is an eigenvalue.

Form here we can proceed to find eigenvectors and then find the matrix $P$.

For a check refer to

- [Matrix A](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%28%28%20-9%2C-3%20%2C-9%29%2C%28%2015%20%2C5%2C15%29%2C%28%203%20%2C1%20%2C3%20%29%29)
- [Matrix B](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%28%28%200%2C0%20%2C0%29%2C%28%20-4%2C2%2C2%29%2C%28%206%2C-3%2C-3%20%29%29)

Comment: Hi, but I need to find a P that $A=P^{-1} B P$ and $B=P^{-1} A P$ Thanks!

Comment: @DonaldZou Find a basis of eigenvectors for $A$ and stack them columnwise in a matrix $R$, such that $AR = RD$, where $D = \operatorname{diag}(0, 0, -1)$. Do the same thing for $B$, such that $BS = SD$. Then $A = RDR^{-1}$ and $D = S^{-1}BS$. Substituting the latter into the former gives $A = RS^{-1}BSR^{-1}$. So you can set $P = SR^{-1}$.

Comment: You need to proceed how explained by Bungo.